# Horizontal alignment of math accents for slanted symbols

Tags: xetex, accents

I want a double widehat accent. Here's my setup: xelatex, accents package, and a definition of dwtilde command (as a reference to dhatheight shows, the code is a modification of someone else's code found on the Web):

```
\newcommand{\dwtilde}[1]{%<br>
    \settoheight{\dhatheight}{\ensuremath{\widetilde{#1}}}%<br>
    \addtolength{\dhatheight}{-0.2ex}%<br>
    \widetilde{\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{\dhatheight}}%<br>
      \smash{\widetilde{#1}}}}
```

I'm using euscript for Euler fonts. Then, a `$\dwtilde{\mathscr A}$` produces two wide tildes with the top one shifted to the left. How do I put the accents aligned horizontally?

Here's an example:

[image: Wrong alignment of two accents]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be useful here so we can see exactly how you are loading the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Run it with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{libertine}
\def\dWDTilde#1{\widetilde{\widetilde{#1\mkern0mu}}}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
foo
$\dWDTilde{\mathscr A}$ 
foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the two accents are aligned with one another, but unfortunately, they're visually too far to the left.  that symbol looks like something that should appear on the funnel of a steamship.

Comment: I don't want to change the fonts (Computer Modern Concrete Postscript fonts with cyrillics + Euler math fonts). I use fontspec to redefine main fonts.